# ElasticSearch edge-ngram and pattern filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-analyzers

I have title like SimpleDoc000155/1 (number of chars is not fixed but is always followed by 9 numbers and / and number), I would like to know how can I analyze this fileds to get the results : 155 and SimpleDoc000155.

Elasticsearch is 2.2 version

My current setting is :

```
"analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter" : [ "code", "lowercase" ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original" : 1,
                    "patterns": ["([1-9].+(?=\/))"]
                }
            },
      "tokenizer" : {
      "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 6,
          "max_gram": 32,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
        }
    }
```

Results i get are

```
{
    "tokens": [{
            "token": "simple",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "simpled",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledo",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc0",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 10,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc00",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc000",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc0001",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 13,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc00015",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 8
        },
        {
            "token": "simpledoc000155",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am a bit lost. Tried a lot but I cannot get 155 back, it seems like pattern_capture is not working correctly.

Thank you for your answers!

Update:

Changed tokenizer from Edgengram to ngram, kinda works but have alot of not needed tokens.

Comment: is there a particular reason you are using edge-ngram tokenizer? Do you also want tokens such as  `s,si,sim,sim, simp`  apart from `SimpleDoc000155 & 155`

Comment: It would be nice to have `sim`, `simpl`, `simple` but word `doc` is not required so i would opt to not have it (i have a large dataset, per say 2m documents) , the most important is to have `SimpleDoc000155/1`, `SimpleDoc000155` and `155` tokens because of copy pasting whole name or just without /1 or typing `155` (id number)

Comment: Try switching to the `keyword` tokenizer, I don't think the `edge_ngram` is doing you any favours here. Also take a look at [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/copy-to.html) so you can store the results in separate fields, which will probably help you when trying to find it back.